# Calendar On Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I  got  Android Market on my emulator. It asked me for Google account.
Everytime I am trying to sign in it says
"You dont have network connection".
Even though my network connection is up and fine.
Kindly provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

This error can be due to the reason because you are not using your machine as server. Are you using internet on your machine via networking? Make your machine as server. It will work fine